# A simple way to distinguish between a fast and a slow android device

Tags: android, performance, libgdx

I created an Android game using libgdx, which runs fine on many devices. I recently used a 'low-end' phone to check my game, and it was not really playable.

Using the Android Studio tools, I figured the problem was not the amount of CPU-time (which was, for this low-end device, steady between 10%-20%). I then created the same game, using the same graphics, but half the size (where a graphic used to be 128x128, it was now 64x64 pixels). This helped a lot, and the game ran fine again.

My question now is, what is a smart way to figure out whether I should use the normal size of graphics, or the 'half' size of graphics?
I have been looking into things like measuring the speed of the CPU (which I think should be a decent indicator for the speed of the gpu as wel, devices with a low-end processor probably probably also have low-end GPU's) but to find the speed of a processor is not as easy as one might like.

What I am thinking of now is the following, if the smallest size of the screensize in pixels is 800 or less, it is a low-end device, otherwise it is a ' normal' device. Yes, very arbitrarily, I know, and I am hoping for a smarter way to find whether a device is reasonably fast.
I have an overview of all screensizes that exist for Android devices (as far as I know) the first eight are (using my '800 or less' rule) low-end devices, the others are normal.

Low-end: 800x480, 800x600,  960x540,  1024x758,  1024x600, 1024x768, 1280x720 & 1366x768

Normal: 1280x800, 1920x1200, 2048x1536, 2736x1824,  1600x900,  1600x1200, 1920x1080, 1920x1280, 2160x1440, 2560x1440, 2560x1600, 2738x2048 & 3840x2160.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you can do is read this system file:

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq

It allows you to know what is the max clock speed of the processor. Then just determine when you should consider it as a slow device or a fast one.

Another way to access the cpu informations is to access /proc/cpuinfo like this:

```
private String getInfo()
{
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("abi: ").append(Build.CPU_ABI).append("n");

    if (new File("/proc/cpuinfo").exists())
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("/proc/cpuinfo")));
            String aLine;
            while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(aLine + "n");
            }

            if (br != null)
            {
                br.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

// Code comes from here http://www.roman10.net/2011/12/31/how-to-get-cpu-information-on-android/ I haven't tested it but should be working. Credits goes to roman10 for the script.

This second method should need root access but I'm not sure for the first one.

Also for the GPU, these are chipsets integrated with the CPU so if you have the CPU id you basically have the GPU.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: This seems like a good way to find out what processor is used, but does not really say something about speeds. Well, at least not if you do not have documentation on every available processor and model, and is also not really future-proof when new processors are introduced.
On the other hand, you answer is the only answer (thanks!) and I will try to use it as a basis for something that works for me.

Comment: Using the CPU reference isn't a good idea as, as you said new models won't be supported. But what you can do, using the second Technic, is to look at the number of cores (shown by: processor: 0, processor: 1 ...) and also the BogoMIPS, it's actually a value calculated by the linux kernel at boot, it's some kind of speed value (not scientific) that you can use to determine ether it's a slow CPU or a fast one. Hope that helps you a bit more.